# Restrict allowed httpMethods using enum

Tags: rest, groovy, enums

I am creating connectors for REST API methods. Some methods has the same method name but performs different HTTP methods.

For example, `createEntity( HttpMethod httpMethod, CreateEntity model )` can perform POST and GET only. What I want is to have an error when `httpMethod` is supplied with PUT or DELETE. The allowed `httpMethod` will depend every method. How can I do this validation inside `CreateEntity.groovy`?

Here is the **HttpMethod.groovy**

```
public enum HttpMethod {
  POST,
  DELETE,
  GET,
  PUT,
  HEAD,
  TRACE,
  CONNECT,
  PATCH
}
```

**CreateEntity.groovy**

```
private String field1;
private String field2;
//write here that only POST and GET are allowed
```

**Connector.groovy**

```
def createEntityQuery ( HttpMethod httpMethod, CreateEntityQuery model ) {
   //perform operations
}
```

this must be valid:

```
createEntity( HttpMethod.POST, new EntityQuery([ field1 : "field1", field2 : "field2" ]))
createEntity( HttpMethod.GET, new EntityQuery([ field1 : "field1", field2 : "field2" ]))
```

this should throw an error:

```
createEntity( HttpMethod.PUT, new EntityQuery([ field1 : "field1", field2 : "field2" ]))
createEntity( HttpMethod.DELETE, new EntityQuery([ field1 : "field1", field2 : "field2" ]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for:

```
public enum HttpMethod {
  POST,
  DELETE,
  GET,
  PUT,
  HEAD,
  TRACE,
  CONNECT,
  PATCH
}

class EntityQuery {
    String field1
    String field2
}

def createEntity(HttpMethod h, EntityQuery q) {
    if(!(h in [HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.GET])) {
      throw new Exception('Only POST and GET methods allowed')
    }
}

createEntity(HttpMethod.PUT, new EntityQuery())
```

?

However it'd be better to expose public methods like `createPostEntity` or `createGetEntity` which will be accepting only `EntityQuery` as an argument and `HttpMethod` will be handled internally.

Comment: Logically yes, hmm I think it is much neater if I have something like configuration class where I will put the 40 api methods and tell there what HTTP methods does every method supports?

Comment: Currently, you've 8 API methods and the chance this number will increase is rather low ;) However having 40 methods that have common logic isn't a good idea. It seems that what you need is to use a builder or factory pattern. Can you please elaborate a bit on what you try to achieve? Having many methods will make the login in each method simpler and easier to use and test.

Comment: @fireflieslive agree, such class could be better. do you have any problems with implementing such class? any particular problem?

Comment: hmm yeah i think exposing it as createEntityPost, createEntityGet is much better. The reason i have one method for several http methods is because i've seen that get implementation vs post implementation has only body and query as field difference. Then what if they support other http methods, which has different structure like post and get. So yeah, i will do expose it as you said. thanks!